# Google Maps Android V2 moveCamera not working

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi and thanks in advance.

I'm doing a project that uses google maps API, so I've followed the google instructions and did everything as it said, and that put a map in my app which I can fully control(zoom etc.),
but when I try moving it to my location, nothing happens, the method doesn't even get called.
Here is my code:(posting pastebin links to improve readability since it's long)

http://pastebin.com/GigFHnHa --activity

http://pastebin.com/yiteCuMD layout

Comment: You mean the `moveMapToMyLocation()` never gets called? Did you try to debug and find out why?

Comment: Is your map instance null when you try to execute the method?

Comment: I checked it, I can see the map, but it won't move it with movecamera.

Comment: Is the myLocation Toast appearing with non null values?

Comment: The toast isn't appearing at all, no matter where I put it(I just put one into onCreate but it didn't show)

Comment: And what about the Logs you are setting? What is the last one that you see in LogCat?

Comment: None of my logs are showing up

Comment: Are you sure? Are you checking the Eclipse LogCat view for yout logs?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LvPhVaeS here is my logcat

Comment: Do you have some filter on your LogCat? The Logs must appear in it.

Comment: Im checking all mesages but no logs are showing up anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61189/discussion-between-joao2fast4u-and-matsura).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to debug your code, setting breakpoints and ensure your `moveMapToMyLocation()` method is being executed. Then, you must check that your `myLocation` object has valid latitude and longitude values. The camera won't move if it is null.